# Can we merge JAVA_OPTS variables through recipe in chef?

Tags: linux, chef-infra

I have installed Java through some cookbook and have set some default variables, now I want to add some more variables (Application specific) through my cookbook. How can I do that through Recipes in Chef. I tried to pass some variables in `setenv.sh` but it is overriding the default values instead I want to merge the variables and override existing variable values.

My code in `setenv.sh`:

```
export JAVA_OPTS="$JAVA_OPTS -Xmx2048m"
```

where `$JAVA_OPTS` - default variables

Comment: Installed java using Tomcat cookbook and JAVA_OPTS were exported already, now i want add some more env variables to it but i do not want to go for attribute override.

Answer (score 0):

First way to do it would be to update the attribute defining the bases values in your application cookbook, as the attributes are read before the recipes are evaluated your file would end up with the correct values.

You're not saying with which cookbook you're using so I'll base the example on the [tomcat cookbook](https://github.com/chef-cookbooks/tomcat)

This cookbook define an attribute `default['tomcat']['java_options'] = '-Xmx128M -Djava.awt.headless=true'`

The easiest way it to complement this by using something like

```
default['tomcat']['java_options'] = "#{default['tomcat']['java_options']} -Xmx2048m"
```

The obvious problem is that you end up with 2 `-Xmx` values, usually the JVM will take the latest but it become hard to find what options is at which value when there's a lot of overwriting.

Second option is to take advantage of [jvmargs cookbook](https://github.com/thommay/jvmargs) wich gives helpers functions to deine the java options and use in your `setenv.sh` template at end.